# How do I load a third party PHP library?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a third party php library which I would like to use in a module. How do I do that in Drupal 8? In drupal 7, I have done things like the following code, but `libraries_get_path()` doesn't exist in Drupal 8, and I'm not exactly sure how things change, not that we use namespaces (of which I am a beginner).

```
require(libraries_get_path('twitter-api-php') . '/TwitterAPIExchange.php');
```

And, where should I place my library? Should I create a new libraries directory and put it in the root, just like modules and themes are now in the root?

Comment: libraries_get_path also doesn't exist in Drupal 7 - it comes from the contrib Libraries module `</nitpick>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 8.x-3.x branch of the Libraries module still provides the `libraries_get_path()` function. And (as of now) it looks pretty much unchanged. So you should be able to use it in the same way.

As far as where to put your library, the `libraries_get_libraries()` function has been updated with the following addition to the `$searchdir` array:

```
// Always search the root 'libraries' directory.
$searchdir[] = 'libraries';
```

Which indicates that you can place your libraries in a directory named "libraries" at your site root.

Comment: Ok, I was able to use libraries_get_path and it returned the correct path. But when I tried to require it, I got this error: Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\twitter_pull\Plugin\Block\TwitterAPIExchange'. My code is: require(libraries_get_path('twitter-api-php') . '/' . 'TwitterAPIExchange.php'); Whats wrong?

Comment: @user1015214 Did you get solution for your error? As i am getting similar error on using require.

Answer (score 3):

[Composer](https://getcomposer.org/):

> Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP. It allows you to
>   declare the dependent libraries your project needs and it will install
>   them in your project for you.

plus the [Composer Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_manager) module:

> Composer Manager provides a gateway to the larger PHP community by
>   enabling Drupal modules to more easily use best-in-breed libraries
>   that are managed by Composer.

can handle this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the libraries module and you put your library files in /libraries/library (which is where mine end up using drush make) you can simply call library_load('library') and that will do the require_once for you.

Comment: Library_load() function does not exists in drupal 8 even after installing libraries module. Error is : PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function .

Answer (score 0):

Using  [Composer Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_manager) is good solution but it need access to command line to init Also you can use [module_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/8) like we use it in Drupal7.
Put your Php file in you module directory and use

```
  module_load_include('php', 'modulename','filename');
```