# How to include phpExcel library in controler?

Tags: 8, theming

I have written composer.json in my module, after running this file, I got all phpExcel dependcies included. Structure formed is like

vendor
--phpoffice
---phpexcel
----classes
----phpexcel.php

I am setting classes to psr-0 level for autoloading but **I'm not able to call PhpExcel class in my controller.**

Any idea about this?

@edit

I have read below articles, but can't find satisfactory solution for this issue.
I have implemented below described approach, but still can't figure out whats exactly I'm missing.

> install https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries in
>   project/modules/contrib folder.
>
> Install https://www.drupal.org/project/phpexcel
>
> Installed library from https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel and place
>   it in "libraries" folder at root.

Now when I went to enable my modules it is simply giving me error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Error: Class 'Drupal\libraries\StreamWrapper\LibraryDefinitionsStream'
>   not found in
>   Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\StreamWrapperManager->addStreamWrapper()
>   (line 156 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Core/StreamWrapper/StreamWrapperManager.php).

**If I include the phpexcel library using composer, it get included. But the issue is.**
 This library has no namespaces. And If I call PhpExcel class in my controller,like

```
use PhpExcel/PhpExcel;

$spreadsheet = new SpreadsheetReader($file_path);
```

It gives error **class not found**.

**How can I read excel file using phpExcel library?**

Comment: There are several other questions on Drupal Answers regarding this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/142247/42650, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/127151/42650, and the drupal.org documentation also has this information. Admittedly answers in those questions do need updating for 8.1.x, but are still accurate for 8.0.x.